# Apply X-offset to gcode (re-slicing not possible)

Tags: g-code, anet-a8

I am currently printing the QTrainer aircraft from 3DLabPrint on my Anet A8, via the supplied i3-compatible gcode files.

So far, everything has printed fine, but the main undercarriage part tries to print off the left hand side of the bed by about 5mm.

I have tried manually adding an `M206 X-10` line to the gcode file, just after `G28 ; home all`, however this has not had any effect:

`G90
M83
M106 S0
M140 S65
M190 S65
M104 S220 T0
M109 S220 T0
G28 ; home all
M206 X-10 ; added by me
G1 E-0.8000 F1800
G1 Z0.200 F1002
; layer 1, Z = 0.2
T0
; tool H0.200 W0.450
; skirt
G1 X9.382 Y10.533 F6000
G1 E0.8000 F540
G1 X10.536 Y10.537 E0.0388 F1440
...`

However this does not work and I'm not clear on whether I am using this gcode command correctly, or whether my printer simply doesn't support that command.

Is there another way I can apply an X-offset to the gcode file (or printer) to move it a few cm to the right of the print area?

As I do not own Simplify3D and cannot currently afford it, re-slicing the STL files is unfortunately not an option.

Unfortunately there is no X-adjustment on the X limit switch (although I suppose I could temporarily tape something to the print head, so that it activates the switch sooner?).

My Anet A8 currently runs stock firmware, hooked up to OctoPrint and I have access to a Macintosh desktop computer.

Comment: The reason that M206 does not work for you is that you are on stock firmware. This firmware is Repetier based and does not support this gcode command. If you had flashed the firmware to Marlin it would have worked fine!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use `G92` to change the coordinates the machine "thinks" it's at. If just after homing, you apply

```
G92 X-10
```

the machine now thinks it's at X = -10, while in reality it's at X = 0. This results in everything thereafter behaving as if it is shifted in the positive X direction by 10 mm (since if you then commanded a move to X = 1 the machine would move to what is physically X = 11).